" Run-Time error '70': Permission denied " when running backup code on MS Access
I have an access form to make backup for my project (access 2019) with the following code :
' Save the backup path to tblConfig
Private Sub SaveBackupPath()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblConfig", dbOpenDynaset)

    rs.FindFirst "SettingName = 'BackupPath'"
    If Not rs.NoMatch Then
        rs.Edit
        rs!SettingValue = Me.backupPath.Value
        rs.Update
    End If

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub

' Retrieve the backup path from tblConfig
Private Function GetBackupPath() As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblConfig", dbOpenDynaset)

    rs.FindFirst "SettingName = 'BackupPath'"
    If Not rs.NoMatch Then
        GetBackupPath = rs!SettingValue
    Else
        ' Default path (e.g., USB pen drive)
        GetBackupPath = "C:\myapp\backup\Database_Backup.accdb"
    End If

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Function
Private Sub backupPathBtn_Click()
    Dim dlg As FileDialog
    Dim selectedPath As String

    Set dlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    If dlg.Show = -1 Then
        selectedPath = dlg.SelectedItems(1)
        'gSelectedPath = selectedPath 
        Me.backupPath.Value = selectedPath
        MsgBox "" & selectedPath
    Else
        selectedPath = "C:\myapp\backup"
        'gSelectedPath = selectedPath 
        Me.backupPath.Value = selectedPath
        MsgBox " " & selectedPath
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub cmdBackup_Click()
    Dim sourcePath As String
    Dim backupPath As String

    ' Set the source path to the current database location
    sourcePath = CurrentDb.Name

    ' Get the backup path from tblConfig
    backupPath = GetBackupPath()

    ' Copy the file
    FileCopy sourcePath, backupPath

    MsgBox "Backup created successfully!"
End Sub
Private Sub cbtn_Click()
DoCmd.Close
End Sub

I tried to run the program from deferent location on my pc and thange the backup locations but when i run the command button i got Run-Time error '70': Permission denied, is there a problem in my code or something i messied ?
I tried to run the program to make a backup to my project

Does this answer your question? Automatic backup on Opening database

FileCopy

will throw a permission denied error if the file is currently open. What you can do is to use the FileSystemObject to do that.
Public Function FileCopy(sourceFileName As String, targetFilename As String)
    
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Call fso.CopyFile(sourceFileName, targetFilename, [overwrite]True)
    
    Set fso = Nothing
    
End Function

